# Will MSCoreFonts displaying styles with foreign characters on fc-list affect the way the font works?

Tags: fonts

I recently installed the [MS Core Fonts 2](http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/) on my Linux server so I can use the MS style TTF for my documents, but when I run the `fc-list` command, there are several items that stand out as odd.

Some of the fonts are showing non-English characters as their style designation.

- Example 1: `/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/timesbd.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Έντονα,Bold`
- Example 2: `/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/cour.ttf: Courier New:style=Κανονικά,Regular`
- Example 3: `/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/arial.ttf: Arial:style=Standaard,Regular`

My text is primarily in US English, so I am concerned that when the fonts are applied to my text, the fonts will mis-translate characters rather than just apply the expected italic/bold/font style.  I found [a similar unanswered question](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=69081).

**Are these non-English characters just name designations and can they be safely ignored, or will using these fonts potentially affect the actual data / text characters in a detrimental way?**

Full results of the `fc-list`

```
-bash-4.2$ fc-list | grep ms
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/candaraz.ttf: Candara:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/corbeli.ttf: Corbel:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/timesbd.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Έντονα,Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdana.ttf: Verdana:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/tahoma.ttf: Tahoma:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/corbelz.ttf: Corbel:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/georgiai.ttf: Georgia:style=Italic,Cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/impact.ttf: Impact:style=Regular,Standard
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/ariali.ttf: Arial:style=Πλάγια,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/andalemo.ttf: Andale Mono:style=Regular,normal
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/courbd.ttf: Courier New:style=tučné,Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/timesi.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Πλάγια,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/corbel.ttf: Corbel:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/trebucbi.ttf: Trebuchet MS:style=Bold Italic,Negrita Cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/constanb.ttf: Constantia:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/georgiab.ttf: Georgia:style=Bold,Negreta
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/calibri.ttf: Calibri:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/comic.ttf: Comic Sans MS:style=Regular,normal
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/consolab.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanaz.ttf: Verdana:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/cour.ttf: Courier New:style=Κανονικά,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/consola.ttf: Consolas:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/arialbi.ttf: Arial:style=Έντονα Πλάγια,Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/georgiaz.ttf: Georgia:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/times.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Standaard,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/calibrii.ttf: Calibri:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/courbi.ttf: Courier New:style=fed kursiv,Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/constanz.ttf: Constantia:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/cambriab.ttf: Cambria:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/corbelb.ttf: Corbel:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/couri.ttf: Courier New:style=kurzíva,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/constani.ttf: Constantia:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/ariblk.ttf: Arial Black:style=Regular,Standard
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/arial.ttf: Arial:style=Standaard,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/candarai.ttf: Candara:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/consolaz.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/trebucit.ttf: Trebuchet MS:style=Italic,Cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/constan.ttf: Constantia:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/calibriz.ttf: Calibri:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/calibrib.ttf: Calibri:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/trebuc.ttf: Trebuchet MS:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/cambriaz.ttf: Cambria:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/candara.ttf: Candara:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/webdings.ttf: Webdings:style=Regular,normal
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/georgia.ttf: Georgia:style=Regular,obyčejné
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/arialbd.ttf: Arial:style=Έντονα,Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/trebucbd.ttf: Trebuchet MS:style=Bold,Negrita
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/cambriai.ttf: Cambria:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanab.ttf: Verdana:style=Bold,Fett
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/comicbd.ttf: Comic Sans MS:style=Bold,Έντονα
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/candarab.ttf: Candara:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/consolai.ttf: Consolas:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanai.ttf: Verdana:style=Italic,Cursiva
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/timesbi.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Έντονα Πλάγια,Bold Italic
```